# Why does a method of mock return null even though I explicitly set its return value?

Tags: android, junit, mockito, viewmodel, android-livedata

Method that should return a LiveData returns null during junit test.

I have the following classes and interface:

```
class PersonListViewModel(personRepository: PersonRepository): ViewModel() {

    val personList: LiveData<List<Person>> = personRepository.getPersonList()
}

interface PersonRepository {
    fun getPersonList(): LiveData<List<Person>>
}

class PersonListViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var personListObserver: Observer<List<Person>>
    @Mock
    private lateinit var personRepository: PersonRepository

    private lateinit var viewModel: PersonListViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        viewModel = PersonListViewModel(personRepository)

        val personList = listOf(Person("id1"), Person("id2"))
        val personListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Person>>()
        personListLiveData.postValue(personList)

        `when`(personRepository.getPersonList()).thenReturn(personListLiveData)

        //NullPointerException thrown here, personList is null
        viewModel.personList.observeForever(personListObserver) 
    }

    @Test
    fun testPersonListPopulates() {
        assertEquals(2, viewModel.personList.value?.size ?: 0)
    }
}
```

Why is that property still null and how can I get around it to test that the person list gets populated?

Comment: You might want to wait with the creation of your `viewModel`, till you have defined what your `personRespoistory` mock is supposed to return.

Comment: Yes, that did it, thanks!